# How to work with query parameters in GWT

Tags: url, gwt

I didnt found any information even after bunch of searches over internet on how to handle query parameters in GWT application in a nice way.
  I'm newbie in GWT, but I'm very excited of its potential. So I'm trying to figure out how basic things works here.

The thing I need - the possibility to rewrite query parameters in case of some events. For example user see in the browser:
  www.some-site.com/conv.html
  but after some user action I want to change URL to:
  www.some-site.com/conv.html?convId=XXXXX

How can I do it?

p.s. I think that this is possible throught javascript, which I can make by JSNI. But maybe GWT already have this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get you started, you should read the official documentation about [History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). It describes the mechanism that allows passing parameters via the url fragment identifier (www.example.com/index.html**#test=true**) and how it's handled in GWT. The documentation contains examples how to capture and trigger the changes to the url fragment.

You might also be interested with MVP - the Model-View-Presenter pattern that is highly recommended for complex GWT apps. You'll find many questions on SO about it, the official docs also have to parts about it ([part 1](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html), [part 2](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html)). For a quick (ok, the video is hour long, but very informative) introduction you should watch [the presentation by Ray Ryan](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) from Google IO 2009 that started the whole MVP + GWT love ;)

Comment: Thank you for answere and links! It seems that it more complex, as I thought =)

Comment: It's very important to embrace History as soon as possible in your application - adding it as an afterthought can be a really PITA. But if you do it right (hint: MVP and/or just some good architecture) it will lead to a nice division into modules/states in your application (more or less independent), which in turn can be taken advantage of via code splitting (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html). So IMHO it definitely pays of to use History :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function from GWT code:

```
//redirect the browser to the given url

public static native void redirect(String url) /*-{
          $wnd.location = url;
}-*/;
```